# HATEOAS JSON output doesn't have right links

Tags: json, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I am looking at implementing new service in my project where I need to output the data in HATEOAS(HAL+JSON) format. I started looking at spring implementation of the same [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/). When I run the code from that link, it gives nice and expected json output as below:

```
{
  "content":"Hello, User!",
  "_links":{
  "self":{
    "href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=User"
  }
}
}
```

But moment I change the return type to List as shown below.

```
    @RequestMapping("/greeting/{name}" )
    public HttpEntity<List<Greeting>> greeting(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting(String.format(TEMPLATE, name));
        greeting.add(linkTo(methodOn(AuditHistoryController.class).greeting(name)).withSelfRel());


        List<Greeting> greetings = new ArrayList<>();
        greetings.add(greeting);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(greetings, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

It changes the output in the following format.

```
[
{
    "content": "Hello, User!",
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8899/risk-portal/api/greeting/User",
            "hreflang": null,
            "media": null,
            "title": null,
            "type": null,
            "deprecation": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Refer the change in **links**.

Do I need to add anything to it to produce the out with "_links" format rather than the above.

Comment: do you get that response in browser? as I just added Hateoas library and got _links straight away with self link

Comment: Hi @DmitriAlgazin, it's the collection that has problem not the single Greeting object. I hope you changed the code to List?